# Share Windows WiFi with Ubuntu PC through wired LAN

Tags: windows, ubuntu, wireless-networking, home-networking, connection-sharing

How to setup this?

WiFi Internet connection <> Windows Laptop <> Wired LAN <> Ubuntu PC

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On the Windows PC:

- Connect the PC to the WiFi and ensure Internet connection is working locally
- Connect the PC to the LAN and ensure the Ubuntu LAN IP is reachable
- You'd better use fixed IP adresses on the LAN instead of DHCP, or make DHCP reservations on the LAN router
- Go to Control Pannel > Network & Sharing > Network Connections > right-click on the WiFi connection > Properties

  - WiFi connection: On the Share tab > **Allow other users to connect...** If you don't see the share tab, you may want to disable this feature on the other connections (the wired one) for the tab to appear.
  - WiFi connection: On the Network tab, Internet Protocol version 4 > Properties > Advanced > Disable Auto metric. Use a low metric (eg. **Interface Metric = 5**).
- Run **`ipconfig`** from a command prompt and note the Ethernet connection (wired LAN) IP address (`<IP>`).

On the Ubuntu PC:

- Run **`sudo ip route add default via <IP> proto static metric 50`**

Tips to debug:

- Windows:

  - `ipconfig /all`
  - `route PRINT`
  - `tracert 8.8.8.8`
- Ubuntu:

  - `ifconfig` and `nmcli dev show`
  - `ip route`
  - `traceroute 8.8.8.8`

Comment: You're a life saver dude, I hate the way windows makes you use the GUI for this kind of stuff.